# Can i execute any code when my app is installed on an iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I would like to know if I can execute any code when my app is being (or after it's) installed on an iOS device, actually I can execute the code when the user runs the app for the first time but I don't want the first run to take so long

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute any code until the user launches your app.